Why are all the record type labels blank for my custom object?
I've got a custom object with various record types, and all the labels of existing record types have disappeared when editing or viewing a record. I've added 2 new record types, whose labels do appear for some reason.
I have access to the record types in configuration, but can't see them on when editing.
I'm logged in as a System Administrator user with full read-write permissions for this custom object and all its fields and record types.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?


What do you mean by "I have access to the record types in configuration, but can't see them on when editing."? Where is it you cannot see them? Have you actually looked at the metadata using the Setup > Object Manager? If labels are shown there, have you enabled translation workbench for the org language and are there some explicit overrides setting the labels to a space or non-breaking space, for example?

Yup, that was it, thank you! Not sure how or why that happened, but I definitely never would have found it. Just for completeness: in the screenshot above, you can see the labels are missing when i'm editing the record type for an individual record. The label is also missing on a detail listing, and when viewing the record. This behavior is in both Classic and Lightning Experience. But when I look at the object in Setup > Object manager, I can see them just fine.

Glad this helped you solve your problem. I'll create an answer so you can close this question off.

If when looking at the metadata using the Setup > Object Manager there are labels visible, this may be caused by "translation" overrides.
Check the translation workbench for the org language and whether there some explicit overrides setting the labels to a space or non-breaking space, for example.
